# Using assembly code written for 32-bit in 64-bit application

Tags: encryption, assembly, 64-bit

Can I use the assembly routines for Serpent encryption in the link below written for 32-bit x86 from a 64-bit program on an x86-64 machine?  That is, without launching a separate 32-bit process for it?  If not, does anyone have a pointer to an optimized implementation of Serpent that works in both 32 and 64 bit (LGPL is OK but cannot use GPL since it's a commercial project)?
http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/cryptography_technology/serpent/serpent.asm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to convert the portions of the code that transfer the results and data to/from memory to use 64-bit address registers. Also, stack manipulation code will need to use the 64-bit stack registers. Other than that, it's likely to work without major changes.

Comment: Thank you, bdonlan. I guess I'll try to find a fast C version, I doubt it would be that much slower as long as the decomposition of the S-boxes is identical.

Comment: Adapting it to x86-64 won't be too difficult - mostly changing exx pointer registers to rxx registers. You just can't use it as-is, as it'll truncate stack and data pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems compatible, at least for me (generally, IA32 assembly is pretty backward-compatible, as sizes of registers do not change, there are just new ones added on x86-64). Also, best way is to check it by yourself.

Comment: bdonlan is correct, the code is _not_ compatible due to memory load/store operations; it uses `[esi + ...]` and `[edi + ...]` as address operands, which needs to be changed for 64bit mode.